# React. How to pass an arg to a function called by an onClick without autotriggering it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this piece of code.
Where the problem I am facing is that  is missing a prop which I want to be an id, obtained inside the map function.
Since I am unable to find a way to send the id to the component outside map, I figured I would do this:

This is my render function

```
render() {
    var users = this.state.userList;


    const Table = Reactable.Table, 
          Td = Reactable.Td,
          Tr = Reactable.Tr;

    if (users.length === 0) {
        return <p>loading</p>
    }

    return (

        <div class="maincontainer">
            <div className="content-landing">

                <Table
                     className="table"
                     filterable={['Email']}
                     itemsPerPage={8}
                     currentPage={0}
                     sortable={true}
                >
                    {users.map((row) => {
                        return (

                            <Tr className={row.className}>
                                <Td column="Email">{row.email}</Td>
                                <Td column="Edit" ><FontAwesomeIcon className="editIcon" onClick={this.showModal(row.id)} icon={faEdit} /></Td> //----THIS.SHOWMODAL IS BEING AUTOEXECUTED WITHOUT ACCOUNTING FOR THE CLICKING


                            </Tr>

                        )
                    })}
                </Table>
                 <EditUserModal show={this.state.showModal} close={this.closeModal} row={this.state.rowId}/> //---I WANT THIS TO RECEIVE A row.id FROM THE ABOVE MAP


            </div>
        </div>



    )
}
```

I have written a couple comments in the parts where I want to make the changes.
I also thought about putting `<EditUserModal>` , inside the `<Td>` , but since its an external `npm` module it crashes, it only admits text.

So my solution was, to pass the row.id to the showModal function, and try to set is a state from there.

```
showModal(rowId) {
    // console.log("showmodal state before any click")
    // console.log(this.state.showModal)
    console.log("triggered show modal")
    console.log(rowId)
    this.setState({
        showModal: true,
        rowId: rowId
    }, () => {
        // console.log("clicked show modal")
        // console.log(this.state.showModal)
    });

}
```

I think it should work, but since the function has a `()` , it auto executes without waiting for any click, making my app to crash.

Comment: nevermind i solved it with ```onClick={()=> this.showModal(row.id)}```

Comment: You could try to extract it from the onClick. And assign it to a constant, lambdas inside JSX can impact performance negatively.

Comment: @r3dst0rm https://cdb.reacttraining.com/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578

Comment: @Agney I'm aware of this post. But I'm referring to the docs explicitly: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are executing the function directly: `this.showModal(row.id)`.

You have to use a callBack function to pass `row.id` something like:

`onClick={()=> this.showModal(row.id)}`

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callBack function in the onClick like this:

```
onClick={()=> this.showModal(row.id)}
```

Or you can define the `showModal` function like this:

```
showModal = (rowId) => () => {
    ...
}
```

and `onClick={this.showModal(row.id)}`

For people who does not understand arrow functions, the above solution is similar to this:

```
function showModal(rowId) {
    return function () {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `showModal` function returns another function that will be triggered in the `onClick` event.